# No SVG graph when saving with Gephi

Tags: svg, gephi

I believe this is a problem with Gephi but wanted to verify or see if I am doing something wrong. I have graphs in Gephi that I would like to export. They're totally fine if I export them as PDF or PNG but I would like to do it as a SVG file for zooming in/out. When I export it and try to open it (via Chrome, Internet Explorer, or Firefox) there's nothing there--it's completely blank. I think it's a Gephi issue because I can open other SVG files no problem.

Has anyone else experienced this issue as well? Is there a simple fix or is this is a bug in Gephi?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone, I figured it out--it wasn't a problem with Gephi or the SVG file. The graph was just so large that I didn't even see the scroll bars on the bottom or the sides. It's there!